# Matlab vector in NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, python-2.7, numpy

I am new to `NumPy` and have only limited knowledge of Matlab. I have the following Matlab command to create row and column vectors:

```
X=(-N:N)
Y=column(X.^2)
```

I am trying to create the same thing in `NumPy` but the shape of the vector `X` and `Y` are the same despite doing transpose:

```
import numpy as np
N=10
X=np.arange(-N,N)
Y=X**2.T
print X.shape, Y.shape
```

Could you please let me know if  `np.arange()` is the equivalent of `(-N:N)` in matlab and what is the problem with the column vector in `NumPy`?

Comment: Create a "column vector" by adding a new axis : `(X**2)[:,np.newaxis]`.

Comment: Also you probably know this but if you wanted a shorter way to make a column vector in matlab you could just use the transpose operator ': `Y=X.^2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little more verbose in python:

```
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(-10,11) #same as X=-10:10; in matlab

Y = X**2 # same as X.^2 in matlab
Y.shape = (np.size(Y),1) #forces it to be column vec
```

Comment: no problem! If it solved your problem, could you mark the check mark next to my answer, please!